# How to add title and custom image to a specific location pin in MKMapView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation

I'm adding annotation pins for the locations taken from database in MKMapView. Among all locations, one of the location is a center location.A pin indicating center location will have a different image from rest of the location pins. Also, center location pin should show title when the user taps it. Here is a code I'm trying:

```
  -(void)addPinWithTitle:(NSString *)lat longitude:(NSString*)longi
  {
  //get centerLocation
  NSString* centerLat=[GroupLocation getGroupLat];
  NSString* centerLon=[GroupLocation getGroupLon];

  MKPointAnnotation *mapPin = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
  double latitude =[lat doubleValue];
  double longitude =[longi doubleValue];
  CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
  mapPin.coordinate = coordinate;

  if([lat isEqualToString:centerlat] && [longi isEqualToString:groupLon]){
  map.title=@"demoTitle";
  }
  [myMapView addAnnotation:mapPin];
  }

  - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapview viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
  {
  if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
  return nil;
  static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
  MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [myMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
  if(annotationView)
  return annotationView;
  else
  {
  MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
  reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
  annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

  annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red_dotFromPaint.png"];

  UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
  // [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(writeSomething:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

  annotationView.draggable = YES;
  return annotationView;
  }
  return nil;
  }
```

Using above methods I have shown all locations fetched from database in mkmapview but now I'm not getting how to show a different image for a particular location pin and title when the user taps that centre pin.
Someone, please tell how to achieve this.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code you need to change latitude, longitude, title and subtitle.

## ViewContrller.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import "V3AnnotationView.h"

@interface ViewController () {
    IBOutlet MKMapView *myMapView;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSMutableArray *arrAnnotation = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    V3AnnotationView *annotation = [[V3AnnotationView alloc] init];
    annotation.title = @"Ahmedabad";
    annotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon1.png"];
    annotation.subtitle = @"City";
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(23.0225, 72.5714);
    [arrAnnotation addObject:annotation];

    V3AnnotationView *annotationAirport = [[V3AnnotationView alloc] init];
    annotationAirport.title = @"Airport";
    annotationAirport.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"airport.png"];
    annotationAirport.subtitle = @"Airport";
    annotationAirport.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(23.0734, 72.6266);
    [arrAnnotation addObject:annotationAirport];

    V3AnnotationView *annotationCarParking = [[V3AnnotationView alloc] init];
    annotationCarParking.title = @"Car";
    annotationCarParking.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"carparking.png"];
    annotationCarParking.subtitle = @"Free parking";
    annotationCarParking.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(23.0225, 72.6714);
    [arrAnnotation addObject:annotationCarParking];

    V3AnnotationView *annotationWifi = [[V3AnnotationView alloc] init];
    annotationWifi.title = @"Wifi";
    annotationWifi.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wifi-512.png"];
    annotationWifi.subtitle = @"Free wifi";
    annotationWifi.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(23.0225, 72.7714);
    [arrAnnotation addObject:annotationWifi];

    [myMapView addAnnotations:arrAnnotation];
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

    // Handle any custom annotations.
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[V3AnnotationView class]])
    {
        V3AnnotationView *myAnnotation = (V3AnnotationView *)annotation;
        // Try to dequeue an existing pin view first.
        MKAnnotationView *pinView = (MKAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];
        if (!pinView)
        {
            // If an existing pin view was not available, create one.
            pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];
            //pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
            pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
            pinView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(0, 4);

        } else {
            pinView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        pinView.image = myAnnotation.image;
        return pinView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

#### You need to create class MKAnnotationView and copy below code into your class file

## V3AnnotationView.h

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface V3AnnotationView : MKAnnotationView
@property (nonatomic,assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImage *image;
@end
```

## V3AnnotationView.m

```
#import "V3AnnotationView.h"

@implementation V3AnnotationView
@synthesize title,subtitle,coordinate,image;
```

Comment: Thanks @Vivek for the answer. but this is showing only one annotation in my case there are multiple.

Comment: I got the answer just replaced  this line - [myMapView addAnnotations:arrAnnotation];

To,

[myMapView showAnnotations:arrAnnotation animated:YES];